# Rewrite an item in a list of list

Tags: scheme, racket

This seems straightforward, but I can't seem to find a solution. I want to replace an item within a list of a list with something, *but* if that item appears multiple times then you randomly replace one of them, but not both. I want to do this in ISL+.

I created the function flatten which appends all sublists :

```
(check-expect (flatten '((a b) (c) (d e f g) (h i j)))
              (list 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f 'g 'h 'i 'j))
(define (flatten lol)
  (foldr append empty lol))
```

I also made rewrite, which replaces the value at index n with whatever you choose

```
(check-expect (rewrite '(x x x - x x x x) 3 'x)
              (list 'x 'x 'x 'x 'x 'x 'x 'x))
(define (rewrite ls n val)
  (cond 
    [(empty? ls) (error "error")]
    [(= n 0) (cons val (rest ls))]
    [else (cons (first ls) (rewrite (rest ls) (sub1 n) val))]))
```

The problem is I don't know how to apply this to a list of list and I also don't know how to randomly replace one of items if it occurs more than once. This is what I have for the final product, but it's probably not the way to go:

```
(define (fullreplace b)
  (local [ 
;makes a list of nested lists of each index the element occurs
;problem is that it makes a list of nested lists so I can't use flatten either
(define (position ls ele n)
  (cond [(empty? ls) 0]
        [(equal? ele (first ls)) (list n (position (rest ls) ele (add1 n))) ]
        [else (position (rest ls) ele (+ 1 n))]))]
;lol-full? checks if the item occurs in the list of lists at all
    (if (lol-full? b) b  (rewrite (flatten b) 
                                       (position (flatten b) '- 0)
                                       "item replaced"))))
;just used for testing 
(define lol2 (list
            (list 2 2 2 2)
            (list 4 '- 4 '-)
            (list '- 8 8 8)
            (list 16 '- '- 16)))
```

(fullreplace lol2) may return this or where any of the other '- are located:

```
(list
 (list 2 2 2 2)
 (list 4 '- 4 2)
 (list '- 8 8 8)
 (list 16 '- '- 16))
```

I've been working on this awhile so any new insight would go a long way. Thank you

Comment: Walk the list recursively and increment an accumulator each time a match is found. Select a random number in the interval `[0..accumulator)`. Walk the list a second time incrementing a new accumulator at each match. When the accumulator matches the random number, replace the next match.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. How would I make an accumulator for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "random" part is what makes this problem pathological. If you could just replace the *first* occurrence, it would be easy. But to replace a *random* occurence, you must first know how many occurrences there are. So before you go replacing stuff, you have to go a-counting:

```
(define (count/recursive val tree)
  (cond ((equal? val tree)
         1)
        (else (foldl (λ (next-value total)
                       (cond ((equal? val next-value)
                              (add1 total))
                             ((list? next-value)
                              (+ total (count/recursive val next-value)))
                             (else total))) 0 tree))))
```

Then you need a function that can replace the nth occurrence of a value:

```
(define (replace/recursive val replace-with n tree)
  (cond ((equal? val tree)
         replace-with)
        (else
         (cdr
           (foldl (λ (next-value total/output-tree)
                    (local ((define total (car total/output-tree))
                            (define output-tree (cdr total/output-tree)))
                      (cond ((equal? next-value val)                                  
                             (cons (add1 total)
                                   (cons (if (= total n) replace-with next-value) output-tree)))
                            ((list? next-value)
                             (cons (+ total (count/recursive val next-value))
                                   (cons (replace/recursive val replace-with (- n total) next-value) 
                                         output-tree)))
                            (else (cons total (cons next-value output-tree)))))) (cons 0 empty) tree)))))
```

Finally, you use `random` to pick the instance you will replace, using `count/recursive` to limit how high of a number `random` picks:

```
(define original '((x x (x y x) a b (((c x z x) x) y x x))))
(replace/recursive 'x '- (random (count/recursive 'x original)) original)
```

Comment: It works! I'm about to head off to sleep, but I'll definitely be looking through it tomorrow. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

How to replace all occurences of a value with another value:

```scm
(define (replace-all needle new-value haystack)
  (cond ((equal? needle haystack) new-value)
        ((pair? haystack) 
         (cons (replace-all needle new-value (car haystack))
               (replace-all needle new-value (cdr haystack))))
        (else haystack)))
```

The only thing to change is to check if the first part constituted a change. If it did you don't do the replace on the other half. Use `equal?` to compare structure.

It's *not* random. It will replace the first occurence it finds either by doing `car` before `cdr` or `cdr` before `car`.

Comment: What is needle? Can you give an example of this. Also pairs? doesn't seem to be defined in ISL+

Comment: "Needle" and "haystack" are names used in search algorithms. "Needle" is the thing to find. "Haystack" is the thing to look in. See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/120218/1825 for more information. As for `pair?` (not `pairs?`), this is called `cons?` in ISL. (`pair?` is the standard Scheme name, though, not `cons?`.)